# Linux (Ubuntu,Mint) или Windows XP

Tags: linux, windows, железо, linux-mint

Вопрос в том, что лучше ставить на старый компьютер?

И так, имеется старый компьютер, точных цифр и характеристик не назову, но на борту имеется `1Гб` оперативки DDR1, процессор - возле `1.6Ггц`, стоит операционная система `Windows XP`, которая часто подвисает(даже после очистки), компьютер используется только для учебы, нужны программы типа `Office Word`, возможно `PowerPoint`, знаю, что есть предустановленные `LibreOffice`, но и вместе с эти можно поставить и сам `Office`, используя `Wine` или `PlayOnLinux`(меньше проблем с библиотеками).

И хотелось бы узнать, какая система была бы лучше на слабой машине, один из этих дистрибутивов `Linux` или `Windows XP`? Вопрос в основном в том, что `Ubuntu`, возможно не примет старое оборудование, ну или нужно больше ресурсов чем старый `Windows` и будет больше лагать. Что вы посоветуете?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Вопрос в основном в том, что Ubuntu, возможно не примет старое оборудование...

В Ubuntu *обычно* всё в порядке с поддержкой устаревшего оборудования, исходя из её политики user-friendly.

Помимо оболочки **XFCE**, [советовавшейся Deno](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/497035/199934), существуют и другие, ещё более минималистичные среды рабочего стола, такие как [**LXDE**](http://lxde.org/), [**Fluxbox**](http://fluxbox.org/), [**Openbox**](http://openbox.org/wiki/Main_Page), [**Enlightenment**](https://www.enlightenment.org/)...

P.S. XP тоже можно заставить работать «гладко» на слабых машинах.

Answer (score 4):

Если говорить о Linux попробуй Xubuntu (пользуюсь сам, на мощных и слабых ПК).

xubuntu основана на xfce.

> Xfce «Заточен под производительность. Он запускает приложения быстро,
>   экономя системные ресурсы»

Если выбирать между win и linux то тут каждому свое.

[Официальный сайт xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) / [xubuntu wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xubuntu)

Comment: Хе. Я так вообще обходился дебианом какое-то время.